# Windows 10 - Bitlocker - TPM with USB key - Not working

Tags: windows-10, usb, encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I’ve tried to implement Bitlocker TPM with USB key:

I can see the .bek with ‘dir /A:S’.

After a restart, the system doesn’t find any USB key. Anything I forgot?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your USB drive.  Show hidden files AND system files.  And see if you have a .BEK file on it.  There should be, if there is not then something probably went wrong with the enable process.

USB might need to be less than 512MB in total size for older BIOS systems.

USB should not be bootable, and might need to be NTFS format.